# Spring MVC Hibernate add two ModelAttribute's using <form:hidden>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm testing on a comment/reply system, and I have run up into a problem.
I have a comment and a reply model.

```
@Entity
public class Reply {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int replyId;
    private String body;
    private String replyOwner;
    private Date datePosted;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="commentedOn")
    private Comment commentedOn;
//getters and setters

@Entity
public class Comment {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int comment_id;

    private String commentBody;
    private String commentOwner;
    private Date datePosted;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Reply> replies;
//getters and setters
```

These are the two forms I wish to use:

```
 <c:forEach items="${commentList}" var="comment">
                <div class="comment-box">
                    <div class="comment-head">
                        <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><a
                                href="http://creaticode.com/blog">${comment.commentOwner}</a></h6>
                        <span>${comment.datePosted}</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-content">
                            ${comment.commentBody}
                        <br>
                                <button id="replyButton">Reply</button>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="comments-list reply-list">
                        <li>
                            <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
                            <div id="replym8">
                                <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/commentTest" method="post" commandName="reply">

                                    <div class="comment-box">
                                        <div class="comment-content">
                                            <label for="reply">Reply</label>
                                            <form:textarea path="body" id="reply" class="form-Control" accept-charset="UTF-8"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <c:set var="commentID" value="${comment.comment_id}"/>

                                       <input type="submit" value="Post reply" class="btn btn-default">
                                    </div>


                                </form:form>

                                    </div>


                                <!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
                            <c:forEach items="${replyList}" var="onereply">

                                <c:if test="${onereply.commentedOn.comment_id == onecomment.comment_id}">
                                    <div class="comment-box">
                                        <div class="comment-head">
                                            <h6 class="comment-name"><a
                                                    href="http://creaticode.com/blog">${onereply.replyOwner}</a></h6>
                                            <span>${onereply.datePosted}</span>
                                            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="comment-content">
                                                ${onereply.body}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </c:if>

                            </c:forEach>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
            </div>


    </ul>
</div>


<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/commentTest" method="post" commandName="comment">


    <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="comment-head">
            <label for="comment">Comment_Owner</label>
            <form:textarea path="commentOwner" id="commentOwner" class="form-Control" accept-charset="UTF-8"/>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content">
            <label for="comment">Comment</label>
            <form:textarea path="commentBody" id="comment" class="form-Control" accept-charset="UTF-8"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-default">
</form:form>
```

The problem is in `<form:hidden path="commentedOn" value="${commentID}"/>`, and I've also tried using `<form:hidden path="commentedOn" value="$comment.comment_id"/>`

Either of these two just return error 400.

Here's the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/commentTest")
    public String commentTest(Model model) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        Reply reply = new Reply();
        model.addAttribute("comment", comment);
        model.addAttribute("reply", reply);
        List<Comment> commentList = commentService.getComments();
        List<Reply> replyList = commentService.getRepliesByComment();
        model.addAttribute("replyList", replyList);
        model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList);
        return "commentTest";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/commentTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String commentTestPost(@ModelAttribute("comment") Comment comment, Model model, @ModelAttribute("reply") Reply reply, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "commentTest";
        }
            commentService.addComment(comment);
            commentService.addReply(reply);
            List<Comment> commentList = commentService.getComments();
            List<Reply> replyList = commentService.getRepliesByComment();
            model.addAttribute("replyList", replyList);
            model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList);
            return "commentTest";

    }
```

The `.addComment` and `.addReply` methods just use `.saveOrUpdate` using Hibernate and those two work.

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: You don't have `<form:hidden>` in your form

Comment: try `<form:hidden path="commentedOn.comment_id" value="${comment.comment_id}"/>` for reply's  `commentedOn`

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
  <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
                                <div id="replym8">
                                    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/viewPhoto/${photo.id}"
                                               method="post" commandName="reply">

                                        <div class="comment-box">
                                            <div class="comment-content">
                                                <label for="reply">Reply</label>
                                                <form:hidden path="replyOwner"
                                                             value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}"
                                                             id="replyOwner"/>
                                                <form:textarea rows="1" path="body" id="reply" class="form-Control"
                                                               accept-charset="UTF-8"/>
                                                <form:hidden path="commentedOnRep" value="${onecomment.comment_id}"/>
                                                <input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Reply" name="reply"
                                                       class="btn btn-default">
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                    </form:form>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
```